# Mysql Strict Mode?

Tags: 7, database

Is Drupal 7 running in mysql strict mode?

I am getting errors such as:

- Invalid datetime format: 1292

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is. It is documented on this issue: http://drupal.org/node/303054